# Submit data from HTML form to ESP8266

Tags: esp8266

I need to submit HTML form from my remote website to my ESP8266 server using `POST` method. I'm looking for something like that :

```
    <form action="my esp8266 IP" method="POST">
        <input type="text" name="foo" value="go">
        <input type="submit">
    </form>
```

Can I use IP address in `action` attribute? 
How can I detect and print received data on ESP8266 side?

Comment: Did you google it? https://techtutorialsx.com/2017/03/26/esp8266-webserver-accessing-the-body-of-a-http-request/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can I use IP address in action attribute?

Sure, if your ESP8266 is either on the same internal (behind a NAT router) subnet as your web server, or your ESP8266 has a public IP address.

> How can I detect and print received data on ESP8266 side?

By parsing the data as it comes in through the socket.

If your ESP8266 is on your home network and your website is out on the internet somewhere you will have to arrange some form of port forwarding through your router (outside the scope of this site) and have some way of your website tracking your (most likely dynamic) home IP address. Again, outside the scope of this site.

It is much more common to use protocols such as MQTT or another RESTful API to have your ESP8266 check in with a remote server to request updated data and instructions, rather than a web server blindly pushing the information directly to the ESP8266.  This is because:

- Putting your ESP8266 directly (or indirectly through port forwarding) on the internet is a security nightmare, and
- Putting all the pieces of the jigsaw together to make it work reliably is not trivial.